# How to convert currency in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, converters, currency

I searched a lot for any tools or function that convert me the currency from any thing to any thing...

If there is no functions, is the amount of convert currency fixed or can be change? (I'm asking this because if yes then maybe i can make the calculation by self)

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking about how to convert, say, USD to Euros, then there's a REST API called [Fixer](https://fixer.io/) that provides endpoints that give current exchange rates.  You'll have to hook into their API to get real time rates.